# as adj, + plural nouns + as

Tags: comparison

The sentence pattern "as adj, + a/an singular noun + as" is correct, but I don't know if it's okay with plural nouns. Is the following okay?

> They are as devoted **teachers** as we are.

Comment: Interesting question! Syntactically speaking, your example is perfectly acceptable to me, but it's certainly not a common construction (with the *optional* plural noun). Note that in *I am as good **a teacher** as he is*, we quite naturally include the article before the singular noun - as happens in many other contexts where we have the choice of using a singular or plural noun. But my "singular" example also allows (particularly in AmE) inclusion of a *preposition* - *I am as good **of** a teacher as he is*. But there's no way to incorporate a preposition in the plural version.